# Test coverage tools for MS Test

Tags: c#, unit-testing, open-source, code-coverage

I have a project in VS 2008 and written a MS Test cases for that. I am looking any open source Test Coverage tools which are free (Like NCover) to perform Test Case coverage tools in .net

Pleaes let me know if any one useed any tool which is open source and free

Comment: VS 2008 has a built in coverage tool for use with MSTest. Can't you use that ?

Answer (score 2):

Visual Studio 2008 does test coverage. It's a bit hard to find but works like a charm. Here is a [link with some screenshots](http://tiredblogger.wordpress.com/2008/05/02/test-coverage-tools-in-vs2008/) on how to enable it.

Answer (score 2):

As well as [PartCover](https://github.com/sawilde/partcover.net4) (now moved to github) there is also [OpenCover](https://github.com/sawilde/opencover) which has 32 and 64 bit process support (as well as .NET2 and .NET4) and can be used with TypeMock and Moles.

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio 2008 does test coverage. It's a bit hard to find but works like a charm. Here is a link with some screenshots on how to enable it.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [PartCover](http://sourceforge.net/projects/partcover/)

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio 2008 does test coverage. It's a bit hard to find but works like a charm.